# How the field profile is in a diagonal end of the optical fiber?

Tags: optics, visible-light, experimental-physics, fiber-optics

[image: Fiber with diagonal end]

I would like to know how is the propogation of the beam, let's say Gaussian beam profile, in the end of the fiber? Does it go in shift to the lower side? Does it change its shape? And how the near field (Evanescent field) in this case?

By the way the black line is the core and the gray line is the cladding.

Comment: It change its direction, you can calculate the angle of propagation using Snell's law.

Comment: Thank you alot for your answer, does it change its shape (the gaussian beam) like the curve from one side will have more sloping edge? Because I'm thinking about that the gaussian beam itself will experience different refractive index..